# Switching between window.ready and window.ajaxComplete if data-attribute exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

If HTML has:

- data-load-file
- or
- data-load-content

then use:

- document.ajaxComplete

else

- document.ready

At the moment I'm using two separate files to achieve this

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

//Small bit of code that loads files in
//5 lines of codes

});


//if data-load-file or data-load-content exist
//use $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
//else use $( document ).ready(function() {

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
// or
$( document ).ready(function() {

//Lots and Lots of code that can be executed
//Lots and Lots of code that can be executed
//Lots and Lots of code that can be executed
//1000s of lines of code

});
```

```html
<div data-load-file="menu-footers.html"></div>
```

Comment: `.ready()` is attached to `document`, not `window`

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need both if script is in head and a simple `if()` to determine if such element exists..

```
function lotsOfCode(){
  //Lots and Lots of code that can be executed
}

function smallBitOfCode(){
  //Small bit of code that loads files in
}

// on page load determine which to execute
$(function(){// same as `$( document ).ready`

  if ($('[data-load-file]').length || $('[data-load-content]').length){         
     $( document).ajaxComplete(lotsOfCode);    
  } else {
     smallBitofCode();
  }    
});
```

Make sure any ajax is also inside `$(function(){ })` and is called after the above code.

Comment: For some reason it broke the jquery

Comment: Fixed it… console told me

Comment: Forgot the OR for `data-load-content` just added in answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.holdReady()` to prevent `.ready()` handler from being called,  `.is()` to check is an element exists in `document`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $.holdReady(true);
    
    onload = function() {

      if ($("[data-load-file],[data-load-content]").is("*")) {
        $.holdReady(false);
      } else {
        // will be called
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
          // do stuff
          alert("ajax complete")
        })
        
        $.ajax()
      }
      
      // will not be called
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // do stuff
        alert("ready")
      })

    }
</script>
<body data-do-not-load-file="" data-do-not-load-content="">do not load file
</body>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $.holdReady(true);
    
    onload = function() {

      if ($("[data-load-file],[data-load-content]").is("*")) {
        $.holdReady(false);
      } else {
        // will not be called
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
          // do stuff
          alert("ajax complete")
        })
        
        $.ajax()
      }
      
      // will be called
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // do stuff
        alert("ready")
      })

    }
</script>
<body data-do-not-load-file="" data-load-content="">load file
</body>
```